# A Groovy-rific way to create multiple objects at once?

Tags: groovy

This might be a trivial question, but I'm relatively new to Groovy.

Say I have a simple POJO:

```
class Ident {
    String a,
    String b,
    String c
}
```

Next, I have a function like this on another class:

```
void select(Ident ... idents) {
    // do something for each ident
}
```

Right now, I'm just doing it the Java way:

```
blah.select(new Ident(a1, b1, c1),
            new Ident(a2, b2, c2),
            ...
            new Ident(aN, bN, cN))
```

Obviously, I've shortened the names.

I'm just wondering if there's a Groovy-ier way to rework this. Or is this it?

I know there's a map-based constructor, but I think that's even more verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spread operator on a list if you have a constructor that takes all of the args in the correct order or you can use the map constructor indirectly:

```
import groovy.transform.TupleConstructor

@TupleConstructor // add constructor Ident(a,b,c)
class Ident {
    String a
    String b
    String c
}

def argLists = [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']]

argLists.collect { new Ident(*it) } //spread

argLists.collect { it as Ident } // list coercion

argLists.collect { 
    def map = [['a', 'b', 'c'], it].transpose().collectEntries() 
    new Ident(map) // map constructor
}

argLists.collect { 
    [['a', 'b', 'c'], it].transpose().collectEntries() as Ident // map coercion
}
```